# git commit is giving 'git-together.active' error

Tags: git, commit

I follow the regular steps to commit my code to the git repo. However, I am getting the following error, I am unable to resolve.

**$ git commit -m 'initial pub/sub capability'**

**Error: error getting git config for 'git-together.active'
Caused by: config value 'git-together.active' was not found; class=Config (7); code=NotFound (-3)**

I have my regular user.name and user.email in the local and global config files. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure your repo for git-together ?

Comment: looks like this error:
https://github.com/kejadlen/git-together/issues/44
do you use this tool?

Comment: It looks like you're not actually using Git, but rather using a front end that (eventually) would run a Git command *for* you, but in this case is not getting that far.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out .bashrc included an alias for git-together. No idea how it ended up there. Thanks all! –