# How do I add a config value for 'git-together.active'

Tags: git, git-config

Ran in to a problem and had to uninstall/reinstall Eclipse (Neon).  Having trouble getting connected back to git with the IDE, so I went to the Git Bash command line.

When trying to commit to my local repo, I typed:

```
git commit -m "Added files after reconnected to source control"
```

This returns:

```
Error: error getting git config for 'git-together.active'
Caused by: config value 'git-together.active' was not found; class=Config (7); code=NotFound (-3)
```

This sounds like I'm missing an entry in my config file for 'git-together.active', but I can find no example of how at add this to my config.  I've reviewed all the 'related' questions but can't find a solution.

Thanks for any guidance, I'm a git novice.

Comment: Sounds like you are using https://github.com/kejadlen/git-together perhaps unintentionally?

Comment: `git-together` is not Git. It has you set up an alias/function so that when you run `git commit` you aren't running Git. You're running something else entirely (which may eventually run Git, but the point remains: *you* aren't running Git at all). Hence all the configuration stuff is up to that other program you've installed. Asking people who know about Git is like asking people who have studied Urdu and paintings: not very helpful.

Comment: Matt, thanks for that lead.  I did check and can find no evidence of that.  Torek, I did set an alias for git = git-together earlier, but removed it.  Still experienced the same problem after re-booting.  After reinstalling Eclipse and getting it set up with Git, the problem went way.  I'm both grateful and annoyed (since I'm couldn't isolate why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.bashrc` for any `alias git=git-together`, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67008411/6309).

That is also why git-together has [issue 44](https://github.com/kejadlen/git-together/issues/44)

> A paper cut felt among engineers relates to the practice of aliasing `git` with `git-together` and interacting with repositories that have opted out of git together config.
>
> The UX looks a bit like this at the moment:
>
> ```sh
> git commit -m "making changes"
> Error: error getting git config for 'git-together.active'
> Caused by: config value 'git-together.active' was not found; class=Config (7); >code=NotFound (-3)
> ```
>
> which causes friction and friction is a turn off for wider adoption.
>
> It would be great if instead this tool emitted a warning so that its visible that this repo a person is interacting with is not yet configured for `git-together` but allowed the `git` process to continue.

The OP mentions not finding an alias though:

> After reinstalling Eclipse and getting it set up with Git, the problem went way.

Comment: VonC, I did check my .bashrc and found no evidence of an alias.  I was able to resolve it, see previous remarks.

Comment: @JamieCarsten OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate the quick comments.  After checking for aliases and ensuring I didn't have github.com/kejadlen/git-together running, I opted to reinstall Eclipse Neon and the Git extensions.  This was a business decision (time).  Something I did in setting it up corrected the problem, but I'm annoyed that I can't pinpoint the exact step.

All the research I did before posting the question lead back to what the responders mentioned as well.  Not fond of the solution, but Git at the command line and in Eclipse both function.